# Training multiple models on a single GPU - Keras

Tags: python, parallel-processing, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I have multiple different model architectures that I'd like to train all on the same data. e.g.

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(LSTM(150, input_shape=(input_length, input_dim)))
model1.add(Dense(20))

model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(input_length, input_dim)))
model2.add(Dense(10))
```

I'd like to train them at the same time using the single GPU on my machine. Is there a best way to do this?

This has been asked on the Keras issue tracker, but without a clear answer: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3287

---

For reference, the following was suggested on the [Keras issue tracker](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3287). I'm not sure about the relative merits of the approach.

```
in_1 = Input()
lstm_1 = LSTM(...)(in_1)
out_1 = Dense(...)(lstm_1)

in_2 = Input()
lstm_2 = LSTM(...)(in_2)
out_2 = Dense(...)(lstm_2)

model_1 = Model(input=in_1, output=out_1)
model_2 = Model(input=in_2, output=out_2)

model = Model(input = [in_1, in_2], output = [out_1, out_2])
model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)

model_1.predict(...)
model_2.predict(...)
```